# C++17 find exact arguments of function and pass to template function

Tags: c++, templates, assembly, c++17

I have a template function that I need to call, it looks something like this:

```
template<typename R, typename... A>
R fn_call(qword fn, A... args) {
    using T = R(*)(A...);
    fn = ...
    return ((T)fn)(args...);
}

#define wrapper_call(FUNC, ...) (fn_call<return_type_t<decltype(FUNC)>>((qword)FUNC, __VA_ARGS__))
```

Getting the return type for the function is simple, but I also need each argument. If I use it in its current state, the following will have issues because the stack parameters are not correct after r8.

```
void func(int a1, int a2, int a3, int a4, qword a5)

wrapper_call(func,0,0,0,0,0)
```

the 5th argument will be passed as a 4 byte int, when it must be a qword.

I am using C++17, and **no standard library**

Comment: What is the point of the macro?

Comment: Why taking function as.. `qword`?

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class R, class...Args>
R fn_call_smart( R(*fn)(Args...), std::identity_t<Args>... args ) {
  return fn_call<R, Args...>(reinterpret_cast<qword>(fn), args...);
}
```

just call `fn_call_smart`, or rename it `wrapper_call` and strip out the macro.

`fn_call_smart` deduces the arguments from `fn`.

I don't see the point of your macro.